# How to sending DOM to Image in server(Vuejs)?

Tags: vue.js

Please can anyone me show how to sending Base64 image into server,I am using Dom to image library.

```
//My script
    import domtoimage from "dom-to-image";
        export default {data: function() {return{ post: { image: "" },}
           createPost(post) {
                 var node = document.getElementById("my-node");
                  domtoimage.toPng(node).then(function(dataUrl) {
                  var image = new Image();
                  image.src = dataUrl;
                  document.body.appendChild(image); }) this.$store.dispatch('createPost', post)},}

    //In Action.js
createPost({commit}, post) {axios.post('posts', post).then(res => {commit('CREATE_POST', res.data)})},
```

Comment: Do you wish to send a base64-image along with a post?

Comment: Yes,I know to convert it ,the problem is how to send.

Comment: If you have access to backend API just send an object with post and image like 
`{ post: post, base64image: dataUrl }` and retrieve them on a server side

Answer (score 0):

```
   imgProfile(event) {
       this.image = event.target;
        if (this.image.files && this.image.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.imageData = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.image.files[0]);
            this.SvImage = this.image.files[0];
        }

    },
```

Comment: Thanks for response but i want to save it on server not upload it from local,Let say after convert it into image Url I want to sent it to server.